# Screen completely glitches out when I plug/unplug monitor with laptop on

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, 15.04

I have a mobile i7 running Ubuntu 15.04, and I have a 3 monitor set up including the laptop. Now, everything used to be fine: I could come home from College with my laptop still on and plug in my monitors - works all as expected. But now, if I plug or unplug a monitor, the whole screen freezes, blacks on & off, and only the cursor moves. I can still *click* things, but I can't see anything.

How can I fix this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Did this start happening after an upgrade?

Comment: I am having similar problem, but with ubuntu 12.04. It was working alright before 6 months. Recently the issue started showing up.

Comment: @rpmcruz, the issue was not there when I installed 15.04, and some time after that. I'm unsure what I may have installed to cause this.

Comment: I've found that blindly pressing Alt+F2, then running the command `unity --replace` or `compiz --replace` fixes the issue.